# How to access data from collection in laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have a result in this form

```
RowCollection {#780 ▼
  #heading: array:7 [▶]
  #title: "Sheet1"
  #items: array:3 [▶]
}
```

i have to access heading ,but when i use foreach loop

```
foreach( $data as $key => $value){
echo $value;
}
```

it print out the items array value.So how to access to heading array ?

Comment: Try `getHeading()` method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on my experience in laravel and its var_dumper, items signed with `#` sign in `dd()` output can be accessed as methods with follows pattern :

`get{ItemStudlyCaseName}()`

e.g `getHeading()`  `getTitle()` `getItems()`

and items signed with `+` sign can be accessed as properties.

**Complete Description**

In `dd()` var_dumper output there is three sign :

`#` protected property

`+` public property

`-` private property

protected properties can be accessed by getter methods with `$object->get{PropertyStudlyCaseName}()` pattern.

public properties can be accessed directly. `$object->propertyName`

private properties is not accessible.

For example in Request object:

```
Request {#38 ▼
  #json: null
  #convertedFiles: null
  #userResolver: Closure {#142 ▶}
  #routeResolver: Closure {#143 ▶}
  +attributes: ParameterBag {#40 ▶}
  +request: ParameterBag {#46 ▶}
  +query: ParameterBag {#46 ▶}
  +server: ServerBag {#42 ▶}
  +files: FileBag {#43 ▶}
  +cookies: ParameterBag {#41 ▶}
  +headers: HeaderBag {#44 ▶}
  #content: null
  #languages: null
  #charsets: null
  #encodings: null
  #acceptableContentTypes: null
  #pathInfo: "/"
  #requestUri: "/"
  #baseUrl: ""
  #basePath: null
  #method: "GET"
  #format: null
  #session: Store {#185 ▶}
  #locale: null
  #defaultLocale: "en"
  -isHostValid: true
  -isClientIpsValid: true
  -isForwardedValid: true
  basePath: ""
  format: "html"
}
```

e.g

`#` protected property : `$request->getDefaultLocale()`

`+` public property : `$request->attributes`

`-` private property : `$request->isHostValid`  => returns null

Comment: beauty answer! , it´s really helpfully